# Priting only certain group headers on next page of report in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjEZT.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjEZT.png)I have created a statement on Crystal. In my first header section I have the company details, statement number ect. (Group Header 1b). My second header is in the details section (Group header 1c) and displays the headings of my columns.

If I print a statement with more than one page, I want header 1 and 2 to display on the first page, but only header 2 (with the column headings) on the consecutive pages.

I know I can go to Group expert >> Options >> "Options and then select Repeat group header on each page" but that causes header 1 AND 2 to print on all pages.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following in the Suppress expression for GH1b:

```
OnRepeatedGroupHeader;
```